# WCF identity when moving from dev to prod. environment

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a web service developed with WCF. In the development environment the endpoint has the following identity section under the endpoint configuration.

```
<identity>
    <dns value="myservice.devdomain.local" />
</identity>
```

`myservice.devdomain.local` is the dns name used to reach the development version of the service.

The binding used is:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="myBinding">
        <security mode ="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I am about to put this into production. The binding will be the same, but the address will be a new production address `myservice.proddomain.local`. I have planned to change the dns value in the configuration to `myservice.proddomain.local` in the production environment. However [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130.aspx) MSDN article on WCF Identity makes me worried about the impact on the clients when I change the identity.

There are two clients - one .NET and one Java using this service. Both of those have been developed against the dev instance of the service. The idea is to just reconfigure the endpoint used by the clients, without reloading the WSDL. But if the identity is somehow part of the WSDL and the identity changes when deploying to prod that might not work.

Will the new identity in the prod version cause issues for the clients that were developed using the dev wsdl? Do the Java and the .NET clients handle this differently?

Comment: Java clients are running on windows environment right? Make sure the users have rights on the new Domain, by default they all must be on the same Domain. You can override that by: > client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain
> = domain; client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName
> = userName; client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password
> = pswd; Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: For the Service side: that will depend if you are hosting a Windows Service, IIS or Custom Services The most useful is WAS (IIS7). If you enable Windows security, by default anyone that has rights on the Domain where the service resides it will have rights to run the Services. You can lock down security by creating groups and assigning the groups to the Service in IIS Thanks,
Sebastian